# What is the need of many-to-one relation between connection point and isolated region?

Tags: filenet, filenet-process-engine

While creating a connection point(CP) for a workflow system in FileNet v5.2.1 gives you an option either to create a new isolated region(IR) or to use any of the existing one itself.

What could be the reason to have multiple CPs pointing to a single IR?

Answer (score 1):

Process Engine clients communicate to isolated regions in the database and to the Process Engine server by using a connection point. Each connection point is associated with an isolated region. A connection point identifies a specific isolated region of the workflow database, and gives it a name that workflow-related applications use to access the region.

Ideally you do not, Since it does not associate with any sort of "source-identification" so that for instance I would be able to know which application/service is getting connection to my isolated region.

Saying this, it might be useful when you want to control and segment your third party applications so that you would give each application or group of application a connection point to use and then you would have better control in disasters for instance over which application/application group you want to shut down its connection.